# Future tenses with present perfect

Tags: word-choice

Is the following sentence correct?

> If we call at 5 it will be too late. They will have left.

Or it should  be

> If we call at 5 it will be too late. They would have left.

I want to emphasize the fact that if we call late they won't be at home but using future  tense.

Answer (score 2):

- *If we call at 5[,] it will be too late*

is unremarkable; [LearnAmericanEnglish](https://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Orange%20Level/O12%20Future%20Conditional.html#:%7E:text=The%20future%20conditional%20describes%20something,I%20will%20bring%20my%20dog.) gives the example

> - *If I go to the park tomorrow, I will bring my dog*.

commenting (though I'd avoid their terminology; typing conditionals is rarely done satisfactorily):

> - *The 'future conditional' describes something that might happen in the*
>   *future with a condition. It often uses "if."*

................

The example  OP asks about is essentially a conditional construction with one protasis (the subordinate, if-clause) and **two** apodoses. Think of

- *If we call at 5 they will have left.* ['they will have left' obviously an apodosis]
- *If we call at 5 it will be too late;/:/ – / ... they will have left.*

Just as *call* (present simple for [possible] future event) requires *it will be*, it requires *will have left* not *would have left*, even in a separate sentence.

- *If we called / were to call at 5 it would be too late. They would have left.*

are likewise correctly constructed.